# How to select a related group of items in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data of the form

```
Key    ID      Link       
1      MASTER  123
2      AA      123
3      AA      123
4      BB      123
5      MASTER  456
6      CC      456
```

I would like to be able to select in the same select all linked items matching the selection criteria, plus the linked master. For example, if I have an ID of 'AA', I want the rows with ID = 'AA' to be returned, plus the row with ID = 'MASTER' and a link of 123:

```
1      MASTER  123
2      AA      123
3      AA      123
```

I'm using Oracle 10.2g, so if any special Oracle syntax will make this easier, then that would be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT key, id, link
  FROM the_table
  START WITH id = 'AA'
  CONNECT BY id = 'MASTER' and link = PRIOR link and 'AA' = PRIOR ID
```

Comment: Thanks - this works extremely well. I didn't know the 'PRIOR' syntax very well, and the web links I found didn't have this usage.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID=your_id UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID='MASTER' AND link = (SELECT link FROM table_name WHERE ID=your_id)

That should answer to the question I understood ;)

Comment: Looks like it will give the right answer to me, but I expect my answer will be more efficient.  You'd have to test it on your data to know for sure.

Comment: Yes, your solution uses the nice connect by Oracle syntax. The explain plan looked ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here's an example I think does what you are looking for:

```
select * from my_table where link in
(select link
from my_table
where id = 'AA')
and id in ('AA','MASTER')
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is that you what all the records that have the same "link" as the one with id = AA
firts you need the link field:

```
select i.link from table i
where i.id = YOUR_ID
```

now you "select" the records that have that link

```
select * from table 
where link in (select i.link from table i where i.id = YOUR_ID)
```

This select should give you the records you need...